# C#. Using all files in a folder, and writing a different string in a specific line

Tags: c#, string, folderbrowserdialog

I need your help.

The thing is that my code works, it reads all the files in a folder which are 96 text files and saves the path of each file. 
I then take each file and change the line number 32 in the text file which is 
"Treatment";"1"; nr = 1,2,3,4,5,...,96. 
My program will takes this string and replaces it with a different one, I change the first file for example to "Treatment";"100"; then the last file should be "Treatment";"196";

So to solve this i change the whole line with a new one. But when i write the number to the string first file is right when i start from 1, but files 2-10 are. 12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89, then it starts 2,3,4,5,6,7 from the 11-th file.

Why is this? My code is below.

I tried saving the integer as a string because I though i was somehow accesing a ASCII table. But that works the same, so my code is below any ideas?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            int start = 1;
            string strengur = "\";";
            string myString = start.ToString();

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            //foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
            for(int i = 0; i < 96 ; i++){

                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePaths[i]);
                lines[31] = "\"Treatment!!\";\"" +myString +strengur;
                File.WriteAllLines(filePaths[i], lines);
                start += 1;
                myString = start.ToString();
           }
        }
  }
```

Best Regards 
Sæþór Ólafur Pétursson

Comment: Could you provide us with the file you are using?  Could you also explain what you mean by " I then take each file and change the line number 32 in the text file which is "Treatment";"1"; nr = 1,2,3,4,5,...,96." - I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: How do I add a file to this comment? 

Explanation:

Comment: @Vijay how do I add a file to this comment? 

Explanation: 
I need to be able to change the nr of the treatments im doing. So I have this data in text files. And line 32 have "Treatment";"nr"; And for each experiment I get 96 text files. which ranges from 1-96 in the "nr"; 
I need to be able to start from what number i want instead of 1, so for example if I start with 200 in the first file I would get 296 in the last file.

Comment: Throw the contents of your file in pastebin and put a link in your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Display all these files in windows explorer, sort by name, and then you will see why.

To solve it, you can set your `start` based on each file's `line31`'s current number, and add by `100`. E.g.:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strengur = "\";";
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
                foreach(var file in filePaths)
                {
                    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                    int currentstart = int.Parse(lines[31].Split(';')[1].Trim('\"'));
                    lines[31] = "\"Treatment!!\";\"" + (currentstart+100).ToString() + strengur;
                    File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit based on your comment:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int start = 100; //set this to your user's input
            string strengur = "\";";
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
            foreach(var file in filePaths)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                int currentstart = int.Parse(lines[31].Split(';')[1].Trim('\"'));
                lines[31] = "\"Treatment!!\";\"" + (currentstart+start-1).ToString() + strengur;
                File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The files are sorted by name, my program just needs a user input what integer to start on. So finding the number in each string and adding by 100 is not what im looking for, I think.  
I need to be able to start from where I want like for example 90 then the last file would get 186;

Comment: can't you change 100 in the above code to your user's input??

Comment: Yes, me and my thick skull. Thanks alot ;D it works perfectly. @Bolu. 
You rock!